# Angularjs input field is getting stuck on typing in google chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ionic-framework

I have 4 fields in a form firstname,lastname,email,phone
when i start typing on email and phone field the form gets stuck in Google chrome browser(keyboard typing and mouse click on form section stops working but outside form everything eg:tabs are working), but when i try with Firefox there is no problem.

I tried in Google chrome by removing firstname field now the error occurs only in phone field. likewise when i remove lastname field there was no error.
In general only the first 2 fields are working 3rd field onwards its showing error.
 How can i sole this issue.

```js
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
 
  $scope.usr = {"firstname":"","lastname":"","umail":"","uphone":"","location":["",""]};
  
  if(localStorage.getItem('appusr')!==null){
   $scope.usr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('appusr'));
   console.log($scope.usr);
  }  
  $scope.saveUserDetails = function(){
   if($scope.usr.location[0]==""){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
         $scope.$apply(function(){         
          $scope.usr.location = [position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude];
           
         });
         
    });
    }
   }
   console.log($scope.usr);
   localStorage.setItem("appusr",JSON.stringify($scope.usr));
    
  }
  
   
});
```

```html
   <form ng-submit="saveUserDetails()" name="form" validate>
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="usr.firstname" placeholder="John">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="usr.lastname" placeholder="Suhr">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Email</span>{{usr.email}}
    <input type="email" ng-model="usr.umail" name="umail" placeholder="john@suhr.com">
   
  </label>
  
   <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Phone</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="usr.uphone" placeholder="9999999999">
  </label>
  
  
  <button type="submit" class="button button-full button-positive"><i class="icon ion-person-add"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; Update </button>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: no errors on the console? ever?

Comment: console is not showing error.. The problem is solved when i restart the browser. But i dont know why this happend..